# Fourier series and least squares approximation problem

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

This is from my schools past examination. I'm stuck on $c$ part $i$. I'm guessing the answer is yes as they only differ by a finite number of points, but this is just from intuition.  I'm trying to use part $b$ to solve it but to no avail. Any help please

Comment: You know that $S_n \to f$ in the $L^2$ norm, hence $S_n$ is Cauchy. Explicitly, $\|S_n-S_m\| \le \|S_n-f\|+\|S_m-f\|$.

Comment: @copper.hat I've never seen the $L^2$ norm, nor heard of it so this doesn't help me unfortunately.

Comment: $\|f\|= \sqrt{ \int_a^b f(x)^2 dx }$.

Comment: @copper.hat I see thanks, but we haven't proved that $S_n(x) \to f$ yet, so i'm not sure if this is the right way to go about it

Comment: @copper.hat no we haven't talked about completeness of an orthonormal system but your second comment gives me something to go on, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $m\le n$, then we have $S_n-S_m = \sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k \phi_k$.

Then $(S_n(x)-S_m(x))^2 = \sum_{k_1=m+1}^n \sum_{k_2=m+1}^n a_{k_1} a_{k_2} \phi_{k_1}(x) \phi_{k_2}(x)$.

Since the $\phi_k$ are orthonormal, we have
$\int_a^b \phi_{k_1}(x) \phi_{k_2}(x) dx = \delta_{k_1 k_2}$, which gives
$\int_a^b ((S_n(x)-S_m(x))^2 dx = \sum_{k=m+1}^n a_k^2$.

If we can show that the $a_k$ are square summable then the desired result follows.

Since $f$ is Riemann integrable, we have that $f^2$ is also Riemann integrable
(this result is not immediate) and Bessel's inequality gives
$0 \le \int_a^b |f(x) -S_n(x)|^2 dx = \int_a^b f(x)^2 dx - \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2$,
from which we conclude that th $a_k$ are square summable.

**Aside**: To see that $f^2 $ is integrable, look at [The product of two Riemann integrable functions is integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5693/27978) for example.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: that is the definition of the sequence $S_n(x)$ being *Cauchy* with respect to the $L^2$ norm.

Comment: I've never seen the $L^2$ norm, nor heard of it so this doesn't help me unfortunately.