# The product of two Riemann integrable functions is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

This question may have been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/the-product-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions-is-integrable).

But I would like to know if I can prove it in the following way. If not, why?

***Proof***: Let functions $f,g: S\to\Bbb R$  be integrable, where $S\subset\Bbb R^n$. Let $A$ be the set of discontinuities of $f$, and let $B$ be the set of discontinuities of $g$. Then the product function $fg$ can only be discontinuous on $A\cup B$, since the product of continuous functions is still continuous on $\Bbb R^n\backslash (A\cup B)$.

By integrability,  we know that $A,B$ are of measure 0. Hence $A\cup B$ is of measure 0. Therefore the set of discontinuities of $fg$ is of measure 0. Hence $fg$ is integrable over $S$.$\blacksquare$

Comment: Did you mean to say $f,g:S\to \Bbb R$?

Comment: That works, for bounded functions. But you need to know (the proof of) Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability, while the other proof doesn't use that.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I am trying to prove the more general case.

Comment: So what is $fg$ then?

Comment: @BigbearZzz you are right!

Comment: @SilviaGhinassi The definition of the Riemann integral only applies to bounded functions. (There are extensions to this concept to unbounded functions, but for functions to which these apply the original definition can no longer be used).

Comment: @Thomas Good point. My bad. The main part of my previous comment still holds.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for replying. Does Riemann integral apply to bounded functions over unbounded domains?

Comment: @LTW The original definition does only apply to bounded functions on bounded domains. Also with regard to the domain extensions exist, but they are a ****.