# How can I show that if a function $f$ is integrable, then $f^{n}$ is riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

This seems like a pretty obvious statement to me but when I was going to use it in a proof I realize I need to prove it. Thanks!

Comment: Does this (plus induction on $n$) answer your question? [The product of two Riemann integrable functions is integrable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5693/the-product-of-two-riemann-integrable-functions-is-integrable)

Comment: If $g$ is continuous and $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $g \circ f$ is Riemann integrable. This isn't obvious,  but the proof is not too difficult.